# Function works but won't return HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have a component that returns the following code:

```
  <Popup
    toggled={moveFolderPopup}
    width="50%"
    close={() => setMoveFolderPopup(false)}
  >
    <div className="popup-title">
      {t('view.assets.moveFolderPopup.title')}
    </div>
    <div className="filebrowser-moveFolderPopup-hierarchy">
      {renderFolderStructure(indexFolder.id)}
    </div>
  </Popup>
```

The part that's failing is `renderFolderStructure(indexFolder.id)`
The function looks as follows:

```
const renderFolderStructure = (parentId: string) => {
if (assetFolders !== []) {
  assetFolders.map((folder, i) => {
    if(folder.parentId === parentId) {
      console.log('why wont this work?');
      return <div>{folder.name}</div>;
    }
  });
} else {
  return <div>Error</div>;
}
};
```

Running this code the console prints out "Why wont this work?" 6 times for 6 folders that have matching parentIds. So everything works except that the function won't return `<div>{folder.name}</div>`. I feel like I have done something like this a million times. What's wrong here?

Comment: You're returning in your `.map()` callback, not your `renderFolderStructure()`. You should return the array `.map()` gives you: `return assetFolders.map(...)`

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I simply overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return` to your function:

```js
...
if (assetFolders !== []) {
  return assetFolders.map((folder, i) => { ... }
} else {
...
```

You have to return the result of your map loop. If you call `return` inside of the map loop you will only "write" this result into the array. Read more about map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map